# Upgrade Odoo V12 --> V15 (CE)

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-15

Currently, I'm using Odoo 12 community version on my local system now I want to upgrade from Odoo 12.0 to Odoo 15.0 (CE).

I tried online but it's asking Enterprise subscription code.

When I tried with command as given below giving me following error.
python3.7 <(curl -s https://upgrade.odoo.com/upgrade) test -d  -t 15.0

Unable to get the subscription code of your database.
Your database must be registered to be eligible for an upgrade.

Anyone, please help me, I would be very thankful.
Thank You

Comment: You can try [OpenUpgrade](https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade) to upgrade from one major Odoo version to the next one.

Comment: @Kenly, Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Actually, I'm upgrading for the first time. I followed OpenUpgrade doc but it's not clear to me. 
Can you please refer to some video links or tutorials which explain step by step?

Thank you in advance, have a good day.

Comment: You can start at [Migrating your database](https://oca.github.io/OpenUpgrade/intro.html#migrating-your-database)

Comment: I tried to follow the instruction of above given link but it's still not clear, 

I can't find odoo-bin file in github.com/OCA/openupgrade and even how to openupgradelib. There is no complete command given.

Is there any better solution do you have please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps described in [Running the migration](https://oca.github.io/OpenUpgrade/migration_details.html#running-the-migration).

For versions earlier than 14.0, you will need to run the OpenUpgrade fork rather than Odoo itself.

First, you will need to upgrade from 12 to 13

> Or, for older versions: check out the OpenUpgrade source code from Github for the branches you need. Each branch migrates to its version from the previous version, so branch 13.0 migrates from 12.0 to 13.0. If you are migrating across multiple versions, you need to run each version of OpenUpgrade in order. Skipping versions is not supported.
> The OpenUpgrade repository includes both openupgrade_framework and openupgrade_scripts:
> https://github.com/OCA/openupgrade

Edit the configuration files and command line parameters to point to the database you are going to upgrade. The recommended command line parameters are the:

```
--update all --stop-after-init --load=base,web,openupgrade_framework flags.
```

For versions earlier than 14.0 that are running the OpenUpgrade fork rather than Odoo itself, you do not pass the load parameter.

***Edit:***

Check the [OCA Days 2021 - Raúl Ortiz: Open Upgrade Discussion](https://youtu.be/NbQ78YKrCX4?t=890) for more details.

Comment: Here is what I understand with the doc, please correct me if I'm missing any step or param:
Need to upgrade from 13 to 14 version
1. clone 14 version from git
2. goto odoo14/addons directory
3. clone https://github.com/OCA/openupgrade
4. goto odoo14 directory
5. Run ./odoo-bin -d odoo13_db --update all --stop-after-init

@Kenly, It would be great if you correct me.

Comment: You need to migrate to a newer version (14) so make the `openupgrade_framework` and the `openupgrade_scripts` modules available in the addons path in the Odoo instance of the new version and run it with the following parameters `--update all --stop-after-init --load=base,web,openupgrade_framework`. Check also the [configuration options](https://oca.github.io/OpenUpgrade/migration_details.html#configuration-options)

Comment: Yes, that is what I have written above. when I execute this  "--update all --stop-after-init --load=base,web,openupgrade_framework" command is not working. Do I need to mention the DB of the 13 version? The command that you mention is not working without ./odoo-bin.

Comment: Specify the database you are going to upgrade

Comment: I'm really thankful to you for your valuable time. One more question I have. Is this valid command? ./odoo-bin -d odoo13_db_name --update all --stop-after-init --load=base,web,openupgrade_framework

Comment: Did you add the `openupgrade_framework` to the addons path? Check the [OCA Days 2021 - Raúl Ortiz: Open Upgrade Discussion](https://youtu.be/NbQ78YKrCX4?t=890) for command line parameters used to migrate from Odoo13 to odoo14

Comment: Yes, I'm able to migrate DB into the 14 version now the design is not coming correctly.

Comment: One final question can guide me on why the design not coming properly or give me any solution link. Thank You

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade feature is available only for the Odoo Enterprise customers. You can try https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade or convert your Odoo version to Enterprise

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Actually, I'm upgrading for the first time. I followed OpenUpgrade doc but it's not clear to me. 
Can you please refer to some video links or tutorials which explain step by step?

Thank you in advance, have a good day.